# utf-16-le BOM csv files

Tags: python, csv, unicode, utf-16le

I'm downloading some CSV files from playstore (stats etc) and want to process with python.

```
cromestant@jumphost-vpc:~/stat_dev/bime$ file -bi stats/installs/*
text/plain; charset=utf-16le
text/plain; charset=utf-16le
text/plain; charset=utf-16le
text/plain; charset=utf-16le
text/plain; charset=utf-16le
text/plain; charset=utf-16le
```

As you can see they are utf-16le.

I have some code on python 2.7 that works on some files and not on others:

```
import codecs
.
.
fp =codecs.open(dir_n+'/'+file_n,'r',"utf-16")
 for line in fp:
  #write to mysql db
```

This works until:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf3' in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What is the proper way to do this? I've seen "re encode" use cvs module etc. but csv module does not handle encoding by itself, so it seems overkill for just dumping to a database

Comment: I don't think the csv module and Unicode play well together. Things have probably improved in Python 3.

Comment: yes that is why I stated that it does not handle it ( they recomend using filter functions etc..) so in essence how can I properly handle these files.

Comment: If the tool is fundamentally incapable of handling the job, it's time to find a different tool. I've suggested one possible approach already.

Comment: I must be having trouble explaining myself, I meant that the answers I've seen always refer to it, but it would seem that the module is incapable. However some good answers below i'll be testing.

Comment: and it is not that I do not want to use python 3,  I have some other dependent modules that are not yet migrated and just a lack of time to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried [`codecs.EncodedFile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.EncodedFile)?

```
with open('x.csv', 'rb') as f:
    g = codecs.EncodedFile(f, 'utf8', 'utf-16le', 'ignore')
    c = csv.reader(g)
    for row in c:
        print row
        # and if you want to use unicode instead of str:
        row = [unicode(cell, 'utf8') for cell in row]
```

Answer (score 3):

> What is the proper way to do this?

The proper way is to use Python3, in which Unicode support is vastly more rational.

As a work-around, if you are allergic to Python3 for some reason, the best compromise is to wrap `csv.reader()`, like so:

```
import codecs
import csv

def to_utf8(fp):
    for line in fp:
        yield line.encode("utf-8")

def from_utf8(fp):
    for line in fp:
        yield [column.decode('utf-8') for column in line]

with codecs.open('utf16le.csv','r', 'utf-16le') as fp:
    reader = from_utf8(csv.reader(to_utf8(fp)))
    for line in reader:
        #"line" is a list of unicode strings
        #write to mysql db
        print line
```

Comment: tried this, it yields the same error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf3' in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: What is the entire traceback, with line numbers included?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bime.py", line 138, in <module>
    main()
  File "bime.py", line 126, in main
    daily_user_uninstalls=parsed[10])
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf3' in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)